# Integrated WiFi antenna in metal box (ESP8266 in coffee machine)

Tags: wifi

I'm currently planning a project involving a ESP8266 inside a coffee machine. However, I do not know if the internal antenna is sufficient to communicate with the outside. Alternativly, I could use a U.HF connector and stick an antenna onto the outside of the metal box. Would that be a better solution? Or will both methods fail?

Comment: A vending machine's case is almost certainly going to be grounded. An internal antenna would have little chance of penetrating such a case unless there were large areas not metallic or if it were placed in front of glass or plastic. The external antenna would almost certainly be a better choice.

Comment: Just put an unconnected insulated wire somewhere through the box, then you can use the internal antenna. If the metal box has openings in the order of 1.2 cm (tenth of the wavelength) and your range requirement is low, it might work as well.

Comment: I read @Arsenal's comment as: Get yourself a 15mm drill. :-P

Comment: what about a broadband (ish) patch antenna?